# Thrust produced by a propeller?

Tags: aerodynamics

I am trying to calculate how much thrust a propeller will have to generate so that the drone can attach itself to any mass $M$ and pull it up under a gravitational field that is half as strong as Earth’s. But I found [this](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/propth.html) on how to find the thrust generated by a propeller:

> Simple Momentum Theory
>
> Turning to the math, the thrust $F$ generated by the propeller disk is equal to the pressure jump $\Delta p$ times the propeller disk area $A$:
>
> $$F = \Delta p \cdot A$$
>
> A units check shows that:
>
> $$\text{force} = \frac{\text{force}}{\text{area}} \cdot\text{area}$$
>
> We can use Bernoulli's equation to relate the pressure and velocity ahead of and behind the propeller disk, but not through the disk. Ahead of the disk the total pressure $pt_0$ equals the static pressure $p_0$ plus the dynamic pressure $0.5 \cdot r\cdot V_0^2$.
>
> $$pt_0 = p_0 + 0.5 \cdot r \cdot V_0^2$$
>
> where $r$ is the air density and $V_0$ is the velocity of the aircraft. Downstream of the disk,
>
> $$pt_e = p_0 + 0.5 \cdot r \cdot V_e^2$$
>
> where $pt_e$ is the downstream total pressure and $V_e$ is the exit velocity. At the disk itself the pressure jumps
>
> $$\Delta p = pt_e - pt_0$$
>
> Therefore, at the disk,
>
> $$\Delta p = 0.5 \cdot r \cdot [V_e^2 - V_0^2]$$
>
> Substituting the values given by Bernoulli's equation into the thrust equation, we obtain
>
> $$F = 0.5 \cdot r \cdot A \cdot [V_e^2 - V_0^2]$$
>
> We still must determine the magnitude of the exit velocity. A propeller analysis based on the momentum equation provides this value.
>
> *Note that this thrust is an ideal number that does not account for many losses that occur in practical, high speed propellers, like tip losses. The losses must be determined by a more detailed propeller theory, which is beyond the scope of these pages. The complex theory also provides the magnitude of the pressure jump for a given geometry. The simple momentum theory, however, provides a good first cut at the answer and could be used for a preliminary design.*

Here we need to know the velocity of the drone or in this case the aircraft to find out the thrust. But how do I do that when I am trying to find the exact same thing? I need to know the amount of thrust it needs to generate to generate a force which accelerates my drone more than $5\,\text{m}/\text{s}^2$. How do I then find the thrust without knowing the velocity?

Comment: @DKNguyen are u talking about the terminal velocity? Also i am doing this as an hypothetical project so is there any purely theoretical way to find this?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question citing plain text from the website instead of a screenshot. I also typeset the formulas with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Feel free to add or remove more of the text if needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Thank you I am new on stackexchange so I do not know a lot about it but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag increases as airspeed increases while propeller thrust decreases as airspeed increases. At some point there is an equilibrium where the drag has increased to the same value that the propeller thrust has decreased to. That is the equilibrium speed the aircraft will accelerate to.

You should have gleamed from this that both drag and propeller thrust change with airspeed which means that for a fixed propeller with constant RPM, you *cannot* have a constant acceleration as the net force accelerating the drone decreases as it goes faster and faster. That means the way you framed your specifications is a problem. You say it needs to accelerate the drone at $5\mathrm{m/s^2}$, but at what airspeed?

You also need to formulate a drag vs speed curve and add that force to your the force required to support the mass against gravity and accelerate against gravity.

*(since I assume when you say "drone" you really mean "quadcopter".
The mainstream public does this but it is a *terrible* terminology since there are many kinds of UAVs and drones and not all of them are hovering quadcopters. Many are fixed wing.)*

That gives you the thrust required for your propeller to accelerate at $5\mathrm{m/s^2}$ *at some particular airspeed*.